# Issue with Promise.allSettled()

Tags: javascript, twitter

I built an application that periodically calls the Twitter API to retrieve tweets for 200 different keywords and store them in a database.

For this purpose, I use the [Twitter for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) package:

```
twitterClient.get('search/tweets', {
  q : '$' + keyword,
  result_type : 'recent',
  count : '100'
}
```

The whole process takes about 4 minutes when performed sequentially.

So I would like to make the Twitter API calls in parallel using [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to improve performance.

This way the process is much faster (about 20 seconds). The problem is that it causes a lot of errors like "Error: JSON parseError with HTTP Status: 200 OK". So about 25 calls fail.

Why does this happen? How can I solve this problem?

***EDIT***

I already use Promise.allSettled() to periodically retrieve info about 200 different users:

```
twitterClient.get('users/show', {
  screen_name: userTwitterName
}
```

In this case I don't have any issue.

Comment: 200 calls at a time is probably too many. Try to make a queue of like 20 or 30 calls at a time

Comment: @JeremyThille, apparently it works well with 50 calls at a time, but it's so annoying. I forgot to mention that I'm already using the same approach to get information about 200 users and it's been working great for months.

Comment: Well, unfortunately API servers don't have an infinite calculating power :) You can't hammer them too much, and you're not the only one making calls at any given time. A good practice when calling an API is to go easy on the number of calls.

Comment: I see, I'm not used to making such intensive calls to APIs. I thank you for the advice. I finally made batches of 25 calls, as 50 was still causing errors.